# Find the value that is in both array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

There is a question like this about intersection on SO but it does not help me. 
I have a strict rule to follow.
Original Solution

```
static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int n = A.length;
        int m = B.length;

        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);

        int i = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            if (i < m - 1 && B[i] < A[k]) i += 1;
            if (A[k] == B[i]) return A[k];
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

This solution is correct but not in all situations for example arr1={6,6,6,6} arr2={2,4,5,9,6}

It will not result in 6 
So task was to add only two lines of code to make it work. I added this

```
 int[] acopy = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);
        A = n > m ? A : B;
        B = n > m ? B : acopy;
        n = A.length;
        m = B.length;
```

As a single line now that task will return 6

But when the array is this

int[] x1 = {0, 2, 7, 10, 23, 345, 56, 456, 767, 56, 6, 80, 6, 65};
    int y1[] = {1, 4, 5, 9, 9, 9, 80, 67, 77};

It doesnt return 80 Now I am not sure what i should add , my code should not be changed but a single line of modification can be added.

Comment: I think you need a `for` loop inside your `for` loop

Comment: WIth that i dont need the if statements right ? except for the one that checks eqality

Comment: you need loop in loop，and no need to sort the input array

Comment: The sorting was already added , on this task , and its codility task with instructions not remove but can add

Comment: i add the a second for loop and it seemsto solve it,

Comment: Although i will be glad to see another solution

Comment: A loop is the most straightforward solution, and time complexity is also optimal. I think you can add your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Mis94 said here you only need to increment the index of the side with the lower value and this is my approach to solve this

```
static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int m = B.length;

    Arrays.sort(A);
    Arrays.sort(B);

    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (i < m - 1 && B[i] < A[k]) { i += 1; k--; continue; }
        if (A[k] == B[i]) return A[k];
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I hope that this follows the instructions

Comment: This is nice but the continue key word , i think plays no role here ? @Mostafa Amin

Comment: Without continue you will get an error in some cases like if 
a = {6,6,6,6}   ==> k=0,  A[k]=6
b = {2,4,5,6,9}==> i=0, B[i]=2
then the first if statement is matched making the i = 1 and k = -1
then you will check A[-1] == B[1] resulting in error

Answer (score 2):

I've made some modifications for the original function you've added, but I'm not sure if these modifications satisfy the restrictions you are talking about or not but anyway here's a version that works for all the cases you mentioned:

```
static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
        int n = A.length;
        int m = B.length;

        Arrays.sort(A);
        Arrays.sort(B);

        int i = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < n && i < m;) {
            if (A[k] == B[i]) return A[k];
            if (i <= m - 1 && B[i] < A[k]) i += 1;
            else if (k <= n - 1 && A[k] < B[i]) k += 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Here you need to only increment `k` iff the value of A[k] < B[i] so that you guarantee that on every iteration you increment the index whose value is lower. Also you need to add a check for `i < m` to avoid infinite loop in case there is no match between elements, so you successfully return `-1`

Answer (score 2):

Correct code for merge-like approach [returns](https://ideone.com/gBqMIt) 80 for your example

```
static int solution(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int n = A.length;
    int m = B.length;

    Arrays.sort(A);
    Arrays.sort(B);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m) {
        if (A[i] == B[j]) 
            return A[i];
        else {
            if (A[i] > B[j]) 
                j++;
            else
                i++;
        }
    }     
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give set and hashset a try,

```
Set<Integer> firstSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
Set<Integer> secondSet= new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,6,7,8,9,0,1));
firstSet.retainAll(secondSet);
Integer[] commonData= firstSet.toArray(new Integer[firstSet.size()]);
```

this will put all common values from both Integer array in commonData

Answer (score 1):

slopeSearch searches for a position in the matrix a where the value x is found. For the search to be successful, it is required that each of the rows and columns of the matrix is sorted in a non-decreasing order.

```
    Int [] slopeSearh (int [][] a, int x) {
        Int m = a.length;
        Int n = [0] a.length;
        Int i = 0;
        Int j = n-1;
        While (i<m && j>=0) {
            if (a[i] [j] == x) return new int[] (i,j) ;
            if (a[i] [j] < x) i++;
            else j--;
        }
        Return null;
    }
```

perform slopesearch analysis and express the result of the analysis using asymptotic notation